# Javascript : problem with while loop that does not work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, console.log, counting

In the script below, I'm trying to get a function to find a random number chosen by the system. To help me to find the number :
When the number to find is smaller than what I enter on the interface: I get a message that the number to find is smaller
When the number to find is bigger than the one I enter on the interface: I receive a message that the number to find is bigger
When I find the number, I receive a message telling me that I have found the number in xxx tries. When I find the number in one go, I want to change trial by trial in the message

When I rotate the code below I just have a box to ask me what is the number to guess. Then nothing happens. Can you please help me to fix the code problems in my script below. Could you please also indicate if my approach is correct to count the number of attempts in the code below. How would you proceed ?

```js
function askValue() {
    var answer = window.prompt(
    "Guess the number, enter a number between 1 and 10"
    );
    // keep the answer to use it in the loop
    if (!answer || isNaN(answer)) {
    console.log("Please enter a valid number");
    } else {
    return answer;
    }
}

function guessnumber() {
    var secret_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var guess = askValue();
    var attempts;
    var i = 0;
    var resultMessage = "You won, you take";
    while (win == false) {
    attempts++;
    if (guess < secret_number) {
        console.log("The secret number is bigger");
        i++;
    } else if (guess > Secret_number) {
        console.log("The secret number is smaller");
        i++;
    } else if (guess == secret_number) {
        win = true;
        
    }
    console.log(resultMessage);
    }
}

// call the function
guessnumber();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make your code works by fixing many mistake and bugs some of them:

- using `var` which is old and it's better use the keyword `let` to declare variable!
- checking if the number between 1 & 10: `if (+answer < 1 || +answer > 10)`
- prefix `+`, is just shorthand for `parseInt()` function to convert string to number, *since prompt return string not number*
- many more...
  if you don't understand sth do a comment and I will explain to you!

  ```js
  function askValue() {
      let answer = window.prompt(
      "Guess the number, enter a number between 1 and 10"
      );
      // keep the answer to use it in the loop
      if (!answer || isNaN(answer)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid number");
      } else if (+answer < 1 || +answer > 10) {
      alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
      } else {
      return +answer;
      }
  }
  // Better using `let` than `var`
  function guessnumber() {
      let secret_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      let guess = askValue();
      let attempts = 0; //initialse attempts with zero
      let i = 0;
      let resultMessage = "You won, you take ";
      let win = false; //declare win
      while (win == false) {
      attempts++;
      if (guess < secret_number) {
          alert("The secret number is bigger");
          i++;
          guess = askValue();
      } else if (guess > secret_number) {
          //s lowercase not capital
          alert("The secret number is smaller");
          i++;
          guess = askValue();
      } else if (guess == secret_number) {
          win = true;
          resultMessage += attempts + " attempt" + (i != 1 ? "s" : "");
          alert(resultMessage);
      } else {
          guess = askValue();
      }
      }
  }

  // call the function
  guessnumber();
  ```